# eption 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

i cant figure out this problem. Im deleting a certain SpriteNode, than re-adding it sometimes on a condition, however it crashes every time im calling addChild(). I know a SpriteNode can only have one parent so i dont understand this. Here is the relevant code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event:UIEvent) {
        var touch: UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        for var i=0; i < tileNodeArray.count; i++
        {
            if (node == tileNodeArray[i]) {
                flippedTilesCount++;
                flippedTilesArray.append(tileNodeArray[i])
                let removeAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
                tileNodeArray[i].runAction(removeAction)

                if flippedTilesCount == 2
                {
                    var helperNode1 = newMemoLabelNode("first",x: 0,y: 0,aka: "first")
                    var helperNode2 = newMemoLabelNode("second",x: 0,y: 0,aka: "second")

                    for var k = 0; k < labelNodeArray.count ;k++
                    {
                        if labelNodeArray[k].position == flippedTilesArray[0].position
                        {
                            helperNode1 = labelNodeArray[k]
                        }
                        if labelNodeArray[k].position == flippedTilesArray[1].position
                        {
                            helperNode2 = labelNodeArray[k]
                        }
                    }
                    if helperNode1.name == helperNode2.name
                    {
                        erasedTiles = erasedTiles + 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for var j = 0; j < flippedTilesArray.count ;j++
                        {
                            let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
                            flippedTilesArray[j].runAction(waitAction)
                            //self.addChild(flippedTilesArray[j]);
                        }
                    }

                    flippedTilesCount = 0;
                    flippedTilesArray = []
                    println("erased tiles:")
                    println(erasedTiles)
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you not to use `SKAction.removeFromParent` but remove the node itself by calling:

```
tileNodeArray[i].removeFromParent()
```

instead of:

```
let removeAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
tileNodeArray[i].runAction(removeAction)
```

The problem might be, that the SKActions don't wait for each other to finish. For example if you call the waitAction, the other actions will keep running.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem